# Pass callback function to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, google-image-search

I'm trying to pass a callback function from a controller to a directive.

Here's the callback function code:

```
$scope.onImageSelect = function(image) {
    alert('SET');
    $scope.card.image = image;
};
```

Directive usage:

```
<google-image-search callback="onImageSelect" />
```

Directive code:

```
ngmod.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/templates/template.html',
        scope: {
            callback: '&'
        }
    }
});
```

Callback usage in template:

```
<a data-ng-click="callback(url)"></a>
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'onImageSelect'
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but could not understand where am I wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... how is that callback triggered? What is `callback(url)`?

Comment: onImageSelect should be a function onImageSelect() not a variable

Answer (score 30, accepted):

While calling the expression method from the directive you need to pass the parameter from the directive in `JSON` format, also you should correct your directive `callback` attribute value to pass function like  `callback="onImageSelect(image)"`

**Directive usage:**

```
<google-image-search callback="onImageSelect(image)" />
```

**Directive Template**

```
<a data-ng-click="callback({image: url})"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
<google-image-search callback="onImageSelect(image)" />
```

This example from [AngularJS developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is pretty similar to your case: http://plnkr.co/edit/hYBxk070sgw54RElyWNq?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

**Following code is tested and working..**

```
Directive call in html

<taxcode-picker call-back-fun="calculate_tax(a, b)"></taxcode-picker>
```

Sample Directive code

```
{
scope:'&',
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
 scope.tax = {amount:12, rate:10.50};
 scope.obj = {number:12, value:10};

  scope.call_back = function (tax) {
    scope.callBackFun({a:tax, b:obj});
  }
}

}
```

Sample Controller

```
app.controller("sample", function($scope){
$scope.calculate_tax = function (tax, obj) {

        console.log("tax "+JSON.stringify(tax));

        console.log("obj "+JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -6):

try to change the scope object to be like this

```
scope: {
        callback: '='
    }
```

and it will work

Comment: why all the down votes?  I tried this and it WORKS!  thanks, Ahmed.  It is perfectly legit to pass a function via '='