# How to call method with argument in directives using angularjs 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to call method with argument in directives using angularjs 1.x.

I need to call a method **call** with argument **num**. I do not know how to pass that **num** argument to call method in directive.

```
myApp.directive('cccIrisRender', function () {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            call:'&'
        },
templateUrl:'xyz.html',
controller:[$scope, function($scope){
   $scope.callMe = function(num){
     $scope.call(num);
   }
    }

        ]
    };
});
```

Comment: Can't you just say `$scope.callMe = $scope.call;`? Why do you even need `$scope.callMe`?. Your controller also should be `['$scope', ...]`, not `[$scope, ...]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass callback function to directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440366/pass-callback-function-to-directive)

Comment: Where is `num` coming from ?

Comment: How do you take the parameters in the assigned function to `call`? I think you can just pass it in a object as `$scope.call({data:num})`