# Passing a callback between directives in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When just passing a callback from a page template (with a controller), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31440439/1363) explains correctly how to format the usage of the callback in the directive template with the value as a JSON object, like this:

```
<a data-ng-click="callback({image: url})"></a>
```

But what happens if the directive is just passing on the callback to another directive.
Should it just pass the callback like this:

```
<another-directive data-ng-click="callback()"></another-directive>
```

Or should it pass the same object format like this:

```
<another-directive data-ng-click="callback({image: url})"></another-directive>
```

Or another option?
Right now non of these works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish, so I'll give an example.

You have a controller (`myController`) that calls a directive (`myDirective`) that calls another directive (`anotherDirective`), and you want to pass a "callback" function from `myController` through `myDirective` down to `anotherDirective`.  Here is how you can do it:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = function(param) {
      alert('This function is declared on the main controller but called from a directive a few levels deep.  Parameter: ' + param);
    };
  }])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: `
        <h1>My Directive</h1>
        <another-directive callback="myFunction(b)"></another-directive>
      `,
      scope: {
        myFunction: '&'
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('anotherDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: `
        <h2>Another Directive</h2>
        <button data-ng-click="callback({b: {a: 'hello world'}})">Click Me</button>
      `,
      scope: {
        callback: '&'
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <my-directive my-function="foo(a)"></my-directive>
<div>
```

The key to this starts in the lowest level directive `anotherDirective`:

```
<button data-ng-click="callback({b: {a: 'hello world'}})">Click Me</button>
```

Now remember how `callback` was set on its parent:

```
<another-directive callback="myFunction(b)"></another-directive>
```

And how `myFunction` was initially declared on its parent:

```
<my-directive my-function="foo(a)"></my-directive>
```

I'm struggling to think of a way to explain it properly, but with this example you should be able to see the pattern with how the expressions bubble up to each parent.